# Blender 2.8 select and drag with a single click

Tags: selection-tools

in previous blender releases I used to left mouse selection and with a single click I can select and move a component (vertex, face, object etc.). Now seems this option does not work anymore in blender 2'8, only if I chose right mouse button selection. 
This is a video that shows the problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbzK4-MvWaQ

Answer (score 4):

Using Left click selection you can do this only with a basic selection tool:

[image]